# MST theorem proof

Tags: data-structures, tree, nodes, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Let **G = (V , E)** be a weighted undirected connected graph that contains a cycle, and let **e** be the maximum-weight edge among all edges in the cycle. I need to prove that there exists a minimum spanning tree of **G** which does NOT include **e**.

The idea is intuitively clear and I can show it on a cycle, consisting of 3 nodes. But I do not know how to show that formally for any cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that exists MST with e. Removing e from it, splits tree in two parts. Expecially, it splits cycle nodes into two non empty parts, call them A and B. Since these nodes form a cycle there is at least one more edge between A and B nodes, call it f. Than MST-e+f is a spanning tree with weight less than MST. That means it is not possible to have MST with e.